# Place RadDropDownTree inside bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, telerik

I am trying to place a RadDropDownTree telerik web UI control on a bootstrap modal dialog.
The problem I have is that the filtering textbox of the drop down tree, once placed on the
dialog, cannot receive any user input. Please see the code excerpt that follows:

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server"></telerik:RadScriptManager>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <telerik:RadDropDownTree ID="RadDropDownTree2" runat="server" EnableFiltering="True"  FilterSettings-EmptyMessage="i can't text anything here" >                  
            </telerik:RadDropDownTree>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did see you also asked this question on Telerik forum (http://www.telerik.com/forums/raddropdowntree-in-bootstrap-modal) but did it really solve the problem? I have the same situation and using 'visibility:hidden' instead of the class 'hide' struggles up the code a lot. For example I can't use data-target/data-dismiss and no backdrop will be shown. Did you find any other solution for this?

Comment: @Nurp we used what Magdalena proposed in her post on Telerik forum. It worked for us just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I researched the problematic scenario in detail and found that it is not related to the Telerik DropDownTree control, because it can be reproduced even with a standard absolutely positioned input element. I recorded a video demonstrating that the focus state of the absolutely positioned input element is not fired, but only the active one, which prevents the editing. The strange thing is that in IE the user can type, while in Chrome and Firefox, he/she is not allowed.

Here is the video: http://screencast.com/t/hr5D6j1R77p

Here is the markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        input[type=text]:focus {
            background: red !important;
        }
        input[type=text]:active{
            background: green !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal
        </a>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 4000; top: 300px; left: 200px;">
            <input type="text" name="name" value=" " />
        </div>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you don't use an absolutely positioned text input element the problem does not reproduce. Are you suggesting that the telerik control i am using generates absolutely positioned input controls?

Answer (score 0):

Removing `tabindex="-1"` from the modal will make it work.

But it also has the side effect of making not only the modal's inputs tabbable but all inputs/links/buttons of the page.